# Can I add a checkbox in to Model Forms in Django even if there is no Field in DB for it

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have a model form and I need to add a checkbox to it. This checkbox is not mapped to any database field. Is this possible ? How !

Comment: Did you tried it ... what error are you getting?

Comment: @pratibha it doesn't allow because this new checkbox BoolenField is not in Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which fields of model will be saved when form will be correct through `fields` variable of Meta class

 So you can declare your checkbox and not include it in that property

```
#your model
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

#your model-form
class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    your_checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required = False,label = 'your_checkbox', ...)
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name',  'birth_date'] #your checkbox is missing, so it's model independent
```

Comment: Its working. Thanks a lot. Can I do a check to show this only in edit mode and not during add mode

Comment: try doing the check in template, depends on the mode render or not

Answer (score 0):

Define a Custom ModelForm by specifying model in Meta and declare the required additional field there. After that set form attribute of your Admin class with the name of YourForm.